# Is class="ember-view" important?

Tags: ember.js

I have seen that forcing a class on the `render` helper will make ember forget about the standard `ember-view` class. For example:

```
{{render "userinfo"}}
```

Generates:

```
<div id="ember1097" class="ember-view">
```

But:

```
{{render "userinfo" class="xxx"}}
```

Will generate:

```
<div id="ember1097" class="xxx">
```

I guess the same will happen with the `view` helper.

What effect does this have? Is `ember-view` not really needed? Why is it used then? Or must I take care to include `ember-view` in my forced class? like:

```
{{render "userinfo" class="xxx ember-view"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

This are auto-generated classes/ids provided by ember that help to manage ember states and views.  Unless you are planning to fork the ember.js git and modify it in some way, you can simply ignore these class and id generated values (neither manually add or remove them).

Comment: Still not clear to me why this markup is added if it is not needed by a running ember application. If this is only internal to ember, for testing or whatever, it should not appear in production, should it?

Comment: Ids are needed for fast lookup of elements, but classes aren't.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely ignore the class. Now {{render}} shouldn't add an extra element. What version of ember are you using? It seems to me that's an old one. I think views generate a `div`, but I had a quick look at an app and it doesn't generate a wrapper element.

In either case, for what I remember the class is there so you can style it or use it in your own code, but you can safely ignore it.